# Emacsclient - how do I start in a specific command?

Tags: emacs, emacsclient

I use emacsclient instead of emacs directly.  Suppose I want to start a frame in emacsclient with the command "mu4e" (to run an [excellent little email client](http://www.djcbsoftware.nl/code/mu/mu4e.html)).  For emacs I would simply do `emacs -f mu4e`.  But in emacsclient, if I try the seeming equivalent:

`emacsclient -c --eval mu4e`

I get this:

`*ERROR*: Symbol's value as variable is void: mu4e`

Clearly I need to evaluate a lisp expression to call the function mu4e, but I can't figure out how to do this.  Google searches did not seem to produce anything helpful.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

`mu4e` is a function? Try this: `emacsclient -c --eval "(mu4e)"`

Comment: That did it, thanks!  Couldn't find the syntax for calling a function when I looked around online...